# R - How to deal with "invalid input found on input connection" warning while reading in large file?

Tags: r, regex, text, special-characters

I have a large (1m+ lines) .txt file I'm reading into R. Each line is an excerpt from a news story that uses the characters from its original source, which is causing problems. Some lines will have all ASCII characters, while others don't but do fit into the UTF-8 encoding framework. Still other characters (similar to Dingbats) seem to defy all encodings as do [coding characters](https://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14812/how-to-search-for-unknown-3-digit-characters-with-black-background/2).

I was able to clean the coding characters out using Notepad++, but every time I try to read the full dataset into R, the read or readLines function only reads as far as the first as the first character it can't interpret.

```
> con <- file(description=filepath, open="r", encoding = "UTF-8")
> news <- readLines(con, n = 100000)
invalid input found on input connection 'en_US/en_US_news.txt' # warning message not error
```

The invalid input message appears to be just a warning, but R only reading in up to the first "illegible" character. I tried writing `news` to a .txt file to see on what character it was stopping, but it's not realistic to clean the file manually like this.

How can I use a `try()` or `trycatch()` within a loop to skip any line that has an illegible character?

Comment: have you tried `fread()` or similar?

Comment: Can you get the hex of the naughty text?